# Nature of the subgroup generated by an unfaithful irreducible representation of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

An unfaithful irreducible representation of a finite group forms a subgroup of the group. For example, for the alternating group $A_4$, there is an unfaithful singlet representation which forms the cyclic group, $Z_3$ ($Z_3$ is a subgroup of $A_4$). Another example will be the symmetric group $S_4$ and its unfaithful doublet representation which forms the dihedral group $D_6$ ($D_6$ is a subgroup of $S_4$). Is such a subgroup somehow different from the other subgroups of the group? Can the group be written as some kind of a product involving such a subgroup?

Comment: I would rather think that the (image) of an unfaithful irreducible representation is a *quotient* of the group. After all, if $\rho$ is a representation of $G$, then Sophomore Theorem says that $$G/\operatorname{ker}\rho\sim \operatorname{im}\rho.$$ Indeed, a cyclic group of order three is a quotient of $A_4$. Anyway, the intersection of the kernels of all the irreps is trivial, implying that we can embed $G$ as a subgroup into a product of the form $\prod_i G/\operatorname{ker}\rho_i$. In some special cases more can probably be said.

Comment: Thank you Lahtonen! Thanks for pointing out that the unfaithful representation forms a quotient group and not a subgroup. Also, thank you for letting me know about the Sophomore Theorem. So, the group can be written as a semidirect product $G = \text{ker} \rho\rtimes\text{im} \rho$, isn't it? (which was basically my second question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment an unfaithful representation of a finite group forms a quotient of the group, not necessarily a subgroup.

The question is then are these quotients somehow different? The answer is yes.

An excellent description of this is given in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129/which-finite-groups-have-faithful-complex-irreducible-representations).

My preffered terminology for the subgroup of $G$ generated by minimal normal subgroups of $G$ is the socle of $G$, but it is called the base of $G$ in the post.

Rephrasing the finite case in my preferred terminology, if $G$ is finite then it has an irreducible faithful representation over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if the socle of $G$ is generated by a single class of conjugates in $G$.

As we are talking about quotients, I'm afraid the question about products doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since the quotients are somehow different/special, then does it mean that the corresponding normal subgroups are also different/special? Do such normal subgroups have a specific name?

Comment: Unfortunately it implies nothing about the normal subgroups.